# Excel Chart, Formatting Line with Stack Column Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a stacked column graph, it is duration based, goes for 16 hours, (starting at 4:00 pm on T, and ending at 8 am on T+1)

1. I have the primary axis completed, showing 0 to 20 hours, how can I get the secondary axis to show the real time and line up with the primary, ex: primary axis time 0 = secondary axis = 4 pm, and so on till 12 pm the next day. (20:00 would be 12 pm)
2. Make a line that crosses at 16:00 and/or 8 am on t+2

**Here is a picture of some detail:**

[image: chart image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the question? How you can have two different y-scales on a single chart? Or how to make a line across a chart? What have you found out about those things when you searched?

Comment: @Raystafarian , 1) Is it possible to make 2 y scales? One with duration and one showing actual time? 2)How do I make a line at 16:00 on this chart? I made a column in my data saying 16 but that shows comes up at 4 pm.

Comment: It's like [literally the first result](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-remove-a-secondary-axis-in-a-chart-233bc85c-b3db-46c4-87f8-4ffafe2a1080) when googling "excel 2010 two y axis". Give it a shot.

Comment: To have a second vertical axis, you need a data series plotted to it.  Since you have a stacked chart, presumably your data is all on a single vertical axis?  Do you need a second axis, or do you need a label configuration that shows different, but related values?

Comment: The quickest/easiest method is to add a "helper" data series to your chart and make a combo chart with the "helper" series as a XY/Scatter plot.  Then use that series for your vertical axis labels.  Add a final additional point with a horizontal error bar for your horizontal line (detached from the normal grid lines).

Comment: @dav , I need a second axis, I can make one, Its the formatting of the axis I need help with.

Comment: @dav, could I send you sample data? I have no clue what a helper data series is

Comment: A helper column is simply additional data that you can use to "shape" the chart-in this case add labels and explanatory lines.

Comment: And, no you shouldn't send data.  If anything, post some demo data for others to help you as well.  You'll likely get a couple different ways to accomplish what you need, then you can mark the answer that helped you the most/best answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a second axis, but only secondary labels, I recommend using a helper series formatted as an XY/Scatter plot.  To accomplish this, you need to:

1. Plot and format your data.  In the following sample, the Value 1 and Value are charted as stacked columns.  You can have as many/few series as necessary.
2. Add XY data for your labels.  In the following example, Y Value is charted as an XY and represented as vertical column of dots on the left.  Since they're just there for labels, typically, they'd be formatted with no line and no marker (just invisible).  Then add your data labels-I use Rob Bovey's awesome [Chart Labeler](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm) add-in because it gives maximum flexibility.  The values are just a concantenated string from the two different values desired (hour number and time).
3. Add XY data for your boundary point.  Again, this is formatted as a red diamond, but would typically be invisible since it's only there to anchor the boundary line.
4. Add a horizontal error bar for your boundary point.  You just use the positive error bar with either a value or variable for its length to reach the entire chart width.
5. Format to taste.

Here's a sample:

[image: 2 axis]

Same image, with all the data (not sure why the chart isn't visible):

[image]

Comment: This doesn't include a second axis (per your requirement) but demo's the helper series.

Comment: Is that a pivot chart? How did you stack it? That looks really good.

Comment: No! Stay away from pivot charts (pivot tables are great-the charts aren't).  It's a combination stacked column chart and xy/scatter chart.

Comment: Value 1 and Value are your stacked columns ? which data parts are those?

Comment: Or is your 'labels' data and 'boundary' data  just for the XY?